# Most efficient way to build multiple objects with parameters and pass them into more objects to be added to a list

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, collections

I have built a list of objects which is extremely slow and I need to increase the speed of building the list. The objects added to the list have multiple sub objects themselves, normally 3 objects which changes to 2 or 1 depending on how many data is left to be added.

I was gonna build a sub object data bean as the parameters being passed are mostly the same, only the sub object changes. I believe there is a much more efficient way than how I have produced the list.

This is the code I have at the moment:

```
List<MainObject> list = new ArrayList();
List<Data> dataList = getDataList();
MainObject mainObject;
int limit = 100;


for(int i = 0; i < limit; i += 3) {
                if(i == limit - 1) {
                    list.add(mainObject = new MainObject(new SubObject(dataList.get(i), this, bBool, tabs)));   
                }else if(i == limit - 2) {
                    list.add(mainObject = new MainObject(new SubObject(dataList.get(i), this, bBool, tabs), 
                            new SubObject(dataList.get(i +1), this, bBool, tabs)));
                }else {                    
                    list.add(mainObject = new MainObject(new SubObject(dataList.get(i), this, bBool, tabs), 
                            new SubObject(dataList.get(i +1), this, bBool, tabs), 
                            new SubObject(dataList.get(i +2), this, bBool, tabs)));
                }
}
return list;
```

Parameters "this, bBool, tabs" are all class variables and always the same. I do know that the last else condition will run most of the time, so that should probably be the first condition within the if statements but i'd rather find a better way of building the list all together.

Comment: Did you measure which part is slow? What time complexity are we talking about? What does `extremely slow` mean?

Comment: @MicSim I did not measure which parts are slow as I don't believe the way I have coded this is efficient at all. I initialize so many objects here and felt there might be a quicker way of building this list. The initial building of the list takes a long time which is why I have a limiter set. The dataList itself can be tens of thousands in size.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check the type of list returned by getDataList(); 
   It has to be ArrayList for your usecase - If It is Linkedlist get index call is heavy and time consuming
2. Move the limit-1 and limit-2 cases outside for loop and exit the loop limit-2 
   itself.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to assign new MainObject to variable
2. Change your list of MainObjects to LinkedList. Add operation is more efficient for LinkedList because ArrayList has to rebuild array inside when its full - its time consuming(Or just create ArrayList with limit size: new ArrayList<>(limit);)
3. getDataList() method should return LinkedList

Comment: Ah yes, it totally slipped my mind to add a size to the ArrayList. If I set the MainObject list to an LinkedList I would need to add it to an ArrayList at the end as LinkedLists are slow when it comes to accessing the elements, that is what I need it for.

Answer (score 0):

With your `limit = 100`, there's nothing in the shown code what could be slow. You can surely do some low-level optimizations like proposed by Srini ("Move the limit-1 and limit-2 cases outside"), but the culprit is elsewhere: either in the constructors or in `dataList::get`.

As a quick hack, try `dataList = new ArrayList<>(dataList)` before the loop.